# How to accumulate content into a variable and only then print?

Tags: variable

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\add{One}
\add{Two}
\add{Three}
\print % Only here "One Two Three" will be rendered
\end{document}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example with [etoolbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) (`\gappto` appends globally, you can use `\appto` if you want it locally).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\print{}
\gappto\print{one}
\gappto\print{two}
\gappto\print{three}

and now \print
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myadds{}
\newcommand\add[1]{\expandafter\def\expandafter\myadds
  \expandafter{\myadds#1 }}
\begin{document}
\add{One}
\add{Two}
\add{Three}
\myadds
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this to work even if the `\add`s occur in groups, then change `\def` to `\gdef`.

If you want to be able to add paragraphs as part of your `\add` content, then include `\expandafter\long` at the beginning of the `\add` definition.

This final, all inclusive definition seems functionally equivalent with the built-in system macro `\g@addto@macro`, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myadds{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\add[1]{\g@addto@macro\myadds{#1 }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\add{One}
\add{Two}
\add{Three}
\myadds
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

With the L3 programming layer (now in the LaTeX kernel).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \myadds
\NewDocumentCommand \add { m } { \tl_put_right:Nn \myadds { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\add{One}
\add{Two}
\add{Three}
\myadds

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an entry in the most obscure approach: This puts each entry into a separate savebox.  Its only practical application is if you want to pull them apart again.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@keepgoing
\let\mylist=\@empty
\def\add#1{\@next\@id\@freelist{}{}\sbox\@id{#1}\@cons\mylist\@id}
\def\print{\loop
  \@next\@id\mylist{\@keepgoingtrue}{\@keepgoingfalse}%
  \if@keepgoing
    \unhbox\@id\space
    \@cons\@freelist\@id 
  \repeat}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\add{One}
\add{Two}
\add{Three}
\print
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, so I am going to go out on a limb here. The way I handled dynamic content was by generating LaTeX code in another language—in my case that was Ruby with its ERB templates. Constant elements were in pure LaTeX, while for each accumulated item I generated appropriate LaTeX code using Ruby.

This also enables you to separate data logic from actual output format, if that is possible. However, an ERB template is used to generate the whole LaTeX file, which is then compiled into a PDF—I am not sure what motivates your question, and thus if this works for you.

Here's a sample code logic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{env}
    <% $data.each do |item| -%>
        \strong{item}
    <% end -%>
\end{env}

\end{document}
```