Newcommand with adaptive number of arguments
What I am looking for is a single newcommand, let's call it \wedges, with a variable number of inputs that yields in a flexible way the following result:

I have already written the code for the variable input commands for the unbarred and barred parts isolated, they are respectively \cunei (italian for wedges) and \bcunei (b stands for barred). Thus \wedges = \cunei \wedge \bcunei. The code (inspired from here) is the following and outputs the above picture:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}

% Just to shorten barring z
\newcommand{\bz}{\bar{z}}

% Wedge part (commands are \cunei, \checknextarg, \gobblenextarg)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cunei}[1]{%
    dz^{#1}\checknextarg}
\newcommand{\checknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextarg}[1]{\wedge dz^{#1}\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{}}
\makeatother

% Wedge bar part (commands are \bcunei, \bchecknextarg, \bgobblenextarg, note the b in front)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bcunei}[1]{%
    d\bz^{#1}\bchecknextarg}
\newcommand{\bchecknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\bgobblenextarg}{}}
\newcommand{\bgobblenextarg}[1]{\wedge d\bz^{#1}\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\bgobblenextarg}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
    \cunei{a}{b}{c}{d} \wedge \bcunei{e}{f}{g}
    \]
\end{document}

I am not satisfied with this since in case of only:

it is still quite verbose, the code is: \cunei{a} \wedge \bcunei{b}. Whereas ideally I would like something like \wedges{a}{\bar{b}} to produce it, where the command \wedges has flexible number of inputs and when it detects the \bar{} as input automatically writes d\bz^{}, instead of dz^{} (actually, since the exponents are usually always j,k,l,m, etc I again, as I did for z in the above code, will introduce newcommands as \bj, \bk, \bl, \bm, etc to shorten \bar{j},..., so I want the command to detect \bj, not \bar{j}, if that makes a difference).
Is there a way to do this? If it may help note that unbarred and barred elements are always ordered, first the unbarred ones and then the barred ones. Thanks.

Hello, do the answers to this question answer your problem? Macro - Repeat the pattern for any (even) number of arguments

Wouldn't a comma-separated list be much easier?

There are also macro delimited lists which use \@cons and \@next to add or remove entries.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610633/how-to-accumulate-content-into-a-variable-and-only-then-print/610660?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C22.3505#610660 for example.

I would recommend not to go the “variable number of arguments” way. A comma separated list of exponents is clearer and easier to type.
Here the “conjugates” are prefixed by *.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}

% Just to shorten barring z
\newcommand{\bz}{\bar{z}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cunei}{m}
 {
  \freestyla_cunei:n {#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__freestyla_cunei_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \freestyla_cunei:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__freestyla_cunei_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {*} { \str_head:n {##1} }
     {% conjugate
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__freestyla_cunei_seq { d\bar{z}^{\mspace{1mu}\str_tail:n {##1}} }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__freestyla_cunei_seq { dz^{##1} }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__freestyla_cunei_seq { \wedge }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\cunei{a,b,c,d,*e,*f,*g}
\]

\end{document}


Each item in the list is checked; if it starts with *, d\bar{z}^{\mspace{1mu}<exponent>} is added to the sequence, otherwise dz^{<exponent>}. Finally, the items in the sequence are delivered with \wedge in between any two.
Note: \str_head:n selects the first character, \str_tail:n all except the first.
I added a small space in the “conjugate exponents”. Try without it to see the difference.

Scary, I was going to propose exactly the same syntax...

@campa * is for conjugation, after all!

@egreg just an off-topic curiosity: did you also had to \usepackage{expl3, xparse} to compile your code? Or I have an old Latex version?

@Freestyla La seconda che hai detto (copyright Quelo). English translation: the latter is the correct guess. You must have TL 2019 or earlier: time to update.

@campa a pity you deleted your non-expl3 solution. It could be useful for people developing packages that should stay format-agnostic...

@Rmano It was a safety deletion. Playing with the macro seemed to fail in some cases, so I wanted to look into it. Undeleted.

egreg has already answered, but just for fun a more low-level solution (but with the same input syntax)
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{{\def\foo@i{\def\foo@i{\wedge}}\foo@ii#1,\relax,}}
\def\foo@ii#1,{\ifx\relax#1\else\foo@i\foo@iii#1**\relax\expandafter\foo@ii\fi}
\def\foo@iii#1*#2*#3\relax{d\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#1?}\relax\bar{z}^{#2}\else z^{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\foo{a,b,*c,*d,e,f, * g }
\]
\end{document}



In case a LaTeX distribution is in use with expl3 not older than 2021-05-10 so that \clist_use:nn and \clist_map_tokens:nn are available you can probably use these:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cunei}{m}{
  \exp_args:Ne \clist_use:nn {\clist_map_tokens:nn {#1} {\freestyle_cunei_chkstar:n}}{\wedge}
}
\cs_new:Nn \freestyle_cunei_chkstar:n {
  \use:c {
    use_
    \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1} {i} {
      \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF {#1} {i} {
        \exp_args:Nne \use:nn {\if_meaning:w}{\tl_head:n {#1}}* \else: i\fi:
      }
    }
    i:nn
  }
  {\exp_not:n{d\bar{z}^{\mspace{1mu}\tl_tail:n {#1}}},}
  {\exp_not:n{dz^{#1}},}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\[
\cunei{a,b,c,d,*e, *f,*g}
\]

\end{document}



If one loads xparse, my solution runs also with TL 2018 or 2019.
